# Order of Shema Koleinu in selichot

Tags: yom-kippur, fast-days, selichot, aseres-yemei-teshuva, artscroll

In different Artscroll siddurim, I count no less than 3 different orderings of Shema Koleinu.  The first version is the one I'm most familiar with, so I'll mark changes in the other two with reference to that one.  Everything here is nusach Ashkenaz.

Older Hebrew+English siddur, interlinear weekday siddur, and both interlinear and standard Hebrew+English selichot:

- שמע קולנו
- השיבנו
- אל תשליכנו מלפניך
- אל תשליכנו לעת זקנה
- אל תעזבנו
- עשה עמנו
- אמרינו האזינה
- יהיו לרצון
- כי לך ה' הוחלנו

New (Wasserman) Hebrew+English siddur:

- שמע קולנו
- השיבנו
- אל תשליכנו מלפניך
- אל תשליכנו לעת זקנה
- אל תעזבנו
- עשה עמנו
- ***כי לך ה' הוחלנו***
- אמרינו האזינה
- יהיו לרצון

All Hebrew siddur, and both interlinear and standard Hebrew+English Y"K machzor:

- שמע קולנו
- השיבנו
- ***אמרינו האזינה***
- ***יהיו לרצון***
- אל תשליכנו מלפניך
- אל תשליכנו לעת זקנה
- אל תעזבנו
- עשה עמנו
- כי לך ה' הוחלנו

Why?  I'm going to guess it's that there were different nuschaot in different times or places, but any more information than that would be even better.  Does anyone distinguish between fast days vs. Yamim Noraim vs. Yom Kippur for some reason?

(I'm planning to email Artscroll and post the answer here, unless someone else already has an answer from them.)

Comment: Fwiw I've seen the last in "_nusach S'farad_" synagogues and one (maybe both) of the others in "_nusach Ashk'naz_" synagogues.